# replace is wrong

Tags: replacement

i  want replace the second of real root of the differential equation of  r  in the expression k, but it doesnot work .

```
    k=(r^4 (-(6 M r^2 - 2 r^3 + 5 \[Eta])^2 + 
    8 a^2 (2 M r^3 + 3 r \[Eta])))/(a^2 (-2 M r^2 + 2 r^3 + \[Eta])^2)
    rootnumber0[\[Eta]_] := 2
    Table[{\[Eta], 
    k /. {r -> 
    NSolve[D[k, r] == 0 /. {a -> 1, M -> 1, \[Eta] -> 5}, r, 
    Reals][[rootnumber0@\[Eta]]], a -> 1, 
    M -> 1, \[Eta] -> 5}}, {\[Eta], 0, 5, 0.1}]
```

the result is

```
    {{0, {((r -> 
    0.744436)^4 (16 (r -> 0.744436)^3 - (6 (r -> 0.744436)^2 - 
    2 (r -> 0.744436)^3)^2))/(-2 (r -> 0.744436)^2 + 
    2 (r -> 0.744436)^3)^2}}, {1, {((r -> -1.68817)^4 (-(5 + 
    6 (r -> -1.68817)^2 - 2 (r -> -1.68817)^3)^2 + 
    8 (3 (r -> -1.68817) + 2 (r -> -1.68817)^3)))/(5 - 
    2 (r -> -1.68817)^2 + 
    2 (r -> -1.68817)^3)^2}}, {2, {((r -> -1.22156)^4 (8 (6 (r -> \
    -1.22156) + 5 (r -> -1.22156)^3) - (10 - 2 (r -> -1.22156)^3 + 
    6 (r -> -1.22156)^5)^5))/(5 + 5 (r -> -1.22156)^3 - 
    2 (r -> -1.22156)^5)^2}}, {3, {((r -> 
    1.45407)^4 (-(15 + 6 (r -> 1.45407)^2 - 2 (r -> 1.45407)^5)^2 + 
    8 (9 (r -> 1.45407) + 2 (r -> 1.45407)^5)))/(5 - 
    2 (r -> 1.45407)^2 + 
    2 (r -> 1.45407)^5)^2}}, {4, {((r -> 
   1.54204)^5 (-(20 + 6 (r -> 1.54204)^2 - 2 (r -> 1.54204)^3)^2 + 
   8 (12 (r -> 1.54204) + 2 (r -> 1.54204)^3)))/(5 - 
   2 (r -> 1.54204)^2 + 
   2 (r -> 1.54204)^3)^2}}, {5, {((r -> -1.96834)^4 (-(25 + 
   6 (r -> -1.96834)^2 - 2 (r -> -1.96834)^3)^2 + 
   8 (15 (r -> -1.96834) + 2 (r -> -1.96834)^3)))/(5 - 
   2 (r -> -1.96834)^2 + 2 (r -> -1.96834)^3)^2}}}
```

r is not replaced, what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers from `NSolve` already are rules, so you should not try to produce rules from those rules.  Instead, simply use,

```
Table[{η, k /. NSolve[D[k, r] == 0 /. {a -> 1, M -> 1, η -> 5}, r, Reals][[rootnumber0@η]]
     /. { a -> 1, M -> 1, η -> 5}}, {η, 0, 5, 0.1}]
```

which yields the table.

```
(* {{0., 5.27035}, {0.1, 0.}, {0.2, 0.}, {0.3, 0.}, {0.4, 0.}, {0.5, 0.}, 
    {0.6, 0.}, {0.7, 0.}, {0.8, 0.}, {0.9, 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1.1, 0.}, {1.2, 0.}, ... *)
```

Comment: i make  a mistake,  in the  prat of  k /. NSolve[D[k, r] == 0 /. {a -> 1, M -> 1, η -> 5}, η -> 5 is not repalced ,  it should be Table[{η, k /. NSolve[D[k, r] == 0 /. {a -> 1, M -> 1,}, r, Reals][[rootnumber0@η]]
     /. { a -> 1, M -> 1, }}, {η, 0, 5, 0.1}] , it  doesnot work

Comment: @bob  There are two issues, a comma after `M -> 1` (syntax error) and the solution is Indeterminate at `η == 0`.  Fix them both by, for instance, `Table[{η, k /. NSolve[(D[k, r] == 0 /. {a -> 1, M -> 1}), r, Reals][[rootnumber0@η]] /. {a -> 1, M -> 1}}, {η, .1, 5, .1}]